# ¿Cómo obtengo dos variables de esa consulta?

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener una consulta de solo DOS columnas que me interesan de ese código Mysql: "intervalo" y "%REAL/Capacidad".

Es posible obtenerlas utilizando alguna forma anidada? o formando un subgrupo?

Ejemplo de lo que busco es:

Select
`intervalo`
,`%REAL/Capacidad`
FROM
**CONJUNTO**

donde el **Conjunto** es el codigo siguiente:

```
SET @sumatiempo:= 0;
SET @cantidadanimales:= 0; 
SET @sumapotenciales :=0;
SET @segundosacumulados :=0;
SET @segundos:=0;
SET @potenciales:=0;
SET @potencialesfiltrados:=0;
SELECT
CONCAT(time(tiempoA),' - ',time(tiempoB)) AS intervalo
, @segundos:= IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0) AS `Segundos`
, @cantidadanimales := @cantidadanimales+1 AS `Despostados`
, @segundosacumulados:= IF(@cantidadanimales=1, 1, @sumatiempo:= @sumatiempo + IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0)) AS `Seg Acum`
, @potenciales:= round(IF(@segundos>=30 AND @segundos<=40,1,IF(@cantidadanimales=1,1,@segundos/35)),1) AS `Potenciales`
, @sumapotenciales:= @sumapotenciales + @potenciales AS `Suma Potenciales`
, ROUND((100*@cantidadanimales /@sumapotenciales),1) AS `%REAL/Capacidad`
FROM 
(SELECT UID AS idA, DTM AS tiempoA, DATE(DTM) AS fecha FROM eventos_desposte) AS A,
(SELECT UID AS idB, DTM AS tiempoB,DATE(DTM) AS fecha FROM eventos_desposte) AS  B
WHERE A.idA+1 = B.idB AND date(tiempoB) = '2019-06-19' AND date(tiempoA) = '2019-06-19' AND IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0)>20
```

No quisiera tener que rearmar el código, por eso pregunto si así como está puedo obtener solo dos columnas.

Gracias de antemano!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

investigando logré solucionarlo. El asunto es el siguiente, PHP no permite utilizar los SET @, por lo tanto en el link siguiente, alguien logró lo que buscaba, que es DENTRO de un QUERY estructurar la definición de variables = 0 como las que yo requiero. 
La solución es la siguiente y da el mismo resultado.

Link de fuente de referencia:
https://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/

CÓDIGO SOLUCIONADO:

```
SELECT

CONCAT(time(tiempoA),' - ',time(tiempoB)) AS intervalo
, ROUND((100*(@cantidadanimales := @cantidadanimales+1) /(@sumapotenciales:= @sumapotenciales + (round(IF((IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0))>=30 AND (IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0))<=40,1,IF(@cantidadanimales=1,1,(IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0))/35)),1)))),1) AS `%REAL/Capacidad`

FROM 
(SELECT @cantidadanimales:=0) as a,
(Select @sumapotenciales :=0) AS C,
(SELECT UID AS idA, DTM AS tiempoA, DATE(DTM) AS fecha FROM eventos_desposte) AS A,
(SELECT UID AS idB, DTM AS tiempoB,DATE(DTM) AS fecha FROM eventos_desposte) AS  B
WHERE A.idA+1 = B.idB AND date(tiempoB) = '2019-06-19' AND date(tiempoA) = '2019-06-19' AND IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tiempoA,tiempoB),0)>20
```

Comment: Buenisimo que encontraste la respuesta! ahora, tratemos de ordenar esto. Pone todo solo en una respuesta. Aclara cadda solucion. Acordate en 24 horas de aceptar tu respuesta (pero deja una sola!!!!). Tambien supongo que cuando en esta respuesta dice php, querras decir mysql... Cuando hagas eso, avisame asi te voto positivo la respuesta!